# git can't checkout empty master branch

Tags: git

`git checkout master` game me the following: `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Here are the steps I took starting with repo creation:

```
Daniel@DOVE ~/Desktop/repos/mine                                                              
$ mkdir git-test                                                                              

Daniel@DOVE ~/Desktop/repos/mine                                                              
$ cd git-test                                                                                 

Daniel@DOVE ~/Desktop/repos/mine/git-test                                                     
$ git init                                                                                    
Initialized empty Git repository in c:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/repos/mine/git-test/.git/         

Daniel@DOVE ~/Desktop/repos/mine/git-test (master)                                            
$ git checkout -b feat-a                                                                      
Switched to a new branch 'feat-a'                                                             

Daniel@DOVE ~/Desktop/repos/mine/git-test (feat-a)                                            
$ git checkout master                                                                         
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Why the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error occurs because there's no branch named `master`, so `git checkout` tries to re-interpret it as a path-name instead, and there's no file named `master` either.

You might wonder where branch `master` went, since `git init` creates it.  The answer to *that* is that `git init` doesn't really create it—at least, not quite.  What `git init` does with it is the same as what your `git checkout -b feat-a` does with `feat-a`: set it up as an "unborn branch", so that you're on a branch that doesn't actually exist.

It's the first `git commit` that creates the otherwise-unborn branch.  <s>You were on `feat-a` when you made that first `git commit`, so `master`, which had never really been created, stopped even *potentially* existing at that point.</s>  (Oops, you didn't make a first commit yet, I somehow conjured one out of thin air.  So `feat-a` was also unborn, and still is.  Let's pretend, for the rest of the answer, that you did do a `git commit` to create a first commit.)

You can still `git checkout -b master`, which will create it pointing to the current commit, or `git checkout --orphan master`, which will "half create" it as unborn, waiting for a first commit.  The difference between these is that without `--orphan`, since there's now an existing commit, git can and will fully-create the branch at the current commit.  With `--orphan`, or in the special case of an empty repository, git won't or can't create a new branch name pointing to an existing commit.

Answer (score 0):

Though Git's default branch is named `master`, until there's a commit on it, there's nothing for the name to point to, so switching your `HEAD` to a different branch with `git checkout -b` loses the `master` alias that `HEAD` used to have.

You can see this with `show-ref` in a fresh repository.

```
git init .
git show-ref
# (no output)
```

If you check out a new branch name and commit something, you'll see it gets the `root-commit` designation, and then a reference is available.

```
git checkout -b branch
git commit --allow-empty -m 'First commit'
[branch (root-commit) 0085654] First commit
git show-ref
0085654104e3cfcbbd836555c94ef9ca8e4c26fa refs/heads/branch
```

Usually, that happens on `master` because you don't bother to change branches first, but now the root commit of your repository is on `branch`, and you'll go from there. If you check out `master`, it will get cloned from `branch` just like any other branching would.

```
$ git checkout -b master
Switched to a new branch 'master'
$ g show-ref
0085654104e3cfcbbd836555c94ef9ca8e4c26fa refs/heads/branch
0085654104e3cfcbbd836555c94ef9ca8e4c26fa refs/heads/master
```